# as a 13 year old child my mother forces me to wear hijab, is this not haram?

Tags: hijab

I am uncomfortable doing it and it has driven me away from the religion. I do not want to do it but am being forced, is this ok in Islam? I need a solid point to prove it to my mom

Comment: Haram is a strong word. I assume you are a girl: doing something which Allah orders can hardly be haram. Enforcing it from the beginning could be a wrong educational approach.

Comment: I get from where from where your Mom is coming from and that she wants the best for you. But forcing it may not be best way. If you have not attained puberty, it is not obligatory on you to wear the Hijab. On the contrary, if you are already a woman,  you are advised to analyze why Allah in the Quran asks the women to cover themselves and why it is preferable both for the lady and the society in the long run. Ofcourse, Islam expects the  men to be modest in their attire too but unfortunately, many men are unaware of what an awrah for men is according to Islam.

Answer (score 0):

You should first ask yourself why is your mother requesting you to wear a hijab; who's command is it to actually wear a hijab? Also, ask yourself what's the wisdom behind wearing one and why it's better for an individual to do so because it preserves your character away from harm and keeps you steadfast on the most righteous of things. You also need to believe firmly that every command in the religion by (Allah the All-Knowing, All-Wise, our Creator) is for your benefit first and foremost. You just need to act upon it, and comprehension of the command will become inevitably crystal clear.

May Allah Subhanu Wa Ta'ala Bless you sister!

Answer (score 0):

Assalamoalykum!

No, it's not haram but if she's being very tough so it's not okay because from this, people get away from the deen specially today's people. She should understand how to teach something and then if you still doesn't wear hijab then she should not force you but then you're literally being a munafiq.
I know it's hard sometime but try to understand it's important. Think about the jannah you will get by following what told us by Allah swt and our prophet pbuh.

May Allah guide you.

Assalamoalykum warahmatullahi Wabarakatuhu.

Answer (score 0):

hijab, like other religious duties, becomes obligatory on a girl from the age of 9, which is equivalent to approximately 8 years and nine months in the solar year (1) And parents have the right to impose the hijab on their adult children, but not by beatings and the like. (2)

We have received hadiths from the Infallibles (peace be upon them) that explicitly emphasize the covering of women. In a hadith from Imam Sadegh (as) we read:
"He will not be reconciled to the rent if he attends, unless he is honored, except that he is not honored" (3); (A girl should wear a headscarf after puberty unless she is unable to provide it). Similar to this narration from that Imam, this statement has also been quoted that: "Fasting and hijab are obligatory on a girl who reaches the age of puberty." (4)

(3). Al-Kafi, Klini, Muhammad ibn Ya'qub, researcher / editor: Ghaffari, Ali Akbar, Akhundi Muhammad, Islamic Library, Tehran, 1407 AH, fourth edition, vol. 5, p. 532.
(4). Shiite means, Sheikh Har Ameli, Muhammad ibn Hassan, Al-Bayt Foundation (AS), Qom, 1409 AH, first edition, vol. 4, p. 409.